# Get URL of a newly created asset, iOS 9 style

Tags: ios, swift, alassetslibrary, photokit

`ALAssetsLibrary` is deprecated these days but practically all examples on SO are still making use of it. For my objective, I need to know the URL of the video that was added to the Photo Library so I could share a video to the Instagram app (that's the only way in which Instagram accepts videos). The URL should probably start with "assets-library://..."

This is simple with `ALAssetsLibrary`:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:videoFilePath completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {  // ...
```

Above, the URL is passed as an argument to the completion block. But what about iOS 9 compatible way with `PHPhotoLibrary` class and `performChanges` method?

```
var videoAssetPlaceholder:PHObjectPlaceholder!  // property

// ...

let videoURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Video_.mp4", withExtension: nil)!

let photoLibrary = PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary()
photoLibrary.performChanges({
    let request = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL(videoURL)
    self.videoAssetPlaceholder = request?.placeholderForCreatedAsset
},
completionHandler: { success, error in
    if success
    {
        // The URL of the video asset?
    }
})
```

Comment: Why don't you just save you video locally before sharing it?

Comment: @LeoDabus The way videos are shared, Instagram won't be able to read a video from my app's sandbox

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's what I've ended up with:

```
let videoURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Video_.mp4", withExtension: nil)!

let photoLibrary = PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary()
var videoAssetPlaceholder:PHObjectPlaceholder!
photoLibrary.performChanges({
    let request = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL(videoURL)
    videoAssetPlaceholder = request!.placeholderForCreatedAsset
},
completionHandler: { success, error in
    if success {
        let localID = videoAssetPlaceholder.localIdentifier
        let assetID =
            localID.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(
                "/.*", withString: "",
                options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil)
        let ext = "mp4"
        let assetURLStr =
            "assets-library://asset/asset.\(ext)?id=\(assetID)&ext=\(ext)"

        // Do something with assetURLStr
    }
})
```

Comment: Works beautifully.

Answer (score 5):

Nice answer and pseudo, thanks Desmond.

Here is an updated answer :

**Swift 3**

```
var assetPlaceholder: PHObjectPlaceholder!
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        let assetRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: videoURL as URL!)
        assetPlaceholder = assetRequest?.placeholderForCreatedAsset
    }, completionHandler: { (success, error) in
        if success {
            let localID = assetPlaceholder.localIdentifier
            let assetID = localID.replacingOccurrences(of: "/.*", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.regularExpression, range: nil)
            let ext = "mp4"
            let assetURLStr = "assets-library://asset/asset.\(ext)?id=\(assetID)&ext=\(ext)"

            // Do what you want with your assetURLStr
        } else {
            if let errorMessage = error?.localizedDescription {
                print(errorMessage)
            }
        }
    })
```

**Going further**

Although this works perfectly for the moment, would anyone know a "cleaner" way to get this "assets-library" URL, without this "manual" solution ?

I found this [interesting thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38183613/how-to-get-url-for-a-phasset), but it only gives a "file:///var/..." URL