# What queue do callbacks run on?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I'm using a serial DispatchQueue to read a set of PHAssets and upload them to a remote host one by one.

The code uses PHAsset.fetchAssets() and then within enumerateObjects I add a task to the queue using `queue.async { .. }`. Within the task, I am using `PHImageManager.default().requestImageData`, which reads the contents of the asset and returns it as `Data` by executing a closure.

So, the code that ends up within each of the queued tasks looks like this:

```
self.queue.async {
  PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(
    for: asset,
    options: self.imageRequestOptions()) { (data: Data?, dataUTI: String?, orientation: UIImageOrientation, info: [AnyHashable : Any]?) in

        print( "--> Upload data: \(data?.description ?? "n/a")" )
        usleep( 2000000 )

    }
}
```

My queue is defined like this:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(
  label: "com.myapp.asset_upload_queue",
  qos: .background
)
```

**The issue** I'm running into is that `PHImageManager.requestImageData` returns right away, so the next task starts to read data immediately. The net result is I end up with multiple concurrent uploads and the CPU shoots through the roof the entire time.

I assume the issue is that the callback `PHImageManager.requestImageData`takes is doesn't block the queue thread, so it moves on to the next task. That next task starts reading data right away.

I tried putting what's inside of the callback in a queue, as in:

```
self.queue.async {
  PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(
    for: asset,
    options: self.imageRequestOptions()) { (data: Data?, dataUTI: String?, orientation: UIImageOrientation, info: [AnyHashable : Any]?) in

        self.queue.async {
          print( "--> Upload data: \(data?.description ?? "n/a")" )
          usleep( 2000000 )
        }

    }
}
```

This starts executing the uploads serially, but the `requestImageData` calls are still being executed one after the other, which puts huge strain on the CPU.

**Question:**

How would I control the flow so that `requestImageData` only gets executed once the previous upload is complete?

**Other things I've tried**

My first approach was to try and [get an asset path directly from the Photos framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38183613/how-to-get-url-for-a-phasset), which reportedly can be done by using `requestContentEditingInputWithOptions`. However, I could only get that to work on the simulator and not on any real device.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a semaphore: create it before your queue call, add a wait on the semaphore after the queue call, and signal the semaphore at the end of the code inside the queue execution.