# How to get the path of an image?

Tags: ios, swift, phasset

How can I get the path or directory of the `PHAsset` images?

I came across an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38183613/how-to-get-url-for-a-phasset) written by @diegomen but when I try it like `selectedAssets[0].PHAsset.getURL()`  it asks for a parameter but @diegomen said it doesn't require a parameter from the comments.

Am I applying it wrong?

Or is there other way of getting the images path from `PHAsset`?

NOTE: I found another solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887638/how-to-get-an-alasset-url-from-a-phasset) by @Clay but it doesn't seem to be the good practice to do it.

Comment: Yes, you need to pass a completion block to that answer's `getURL` method. Read all of the comment below that answer.

Comment: PHAsset is not image. It is structure wich contain many information about image and image data. You can get UIImage from this with some quality.

Answer (score 2):

If you have already store image in your local file path and you want to retrive the image file Path from your PHAsset image address then use this function:

```
[asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:[PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions new] completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {
    NSURL *imageURL = contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL;
    }];
```

asset=PHAsset *asset

Answer (score -1):

You should store image to local file. After that you will have file url.

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage);

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *imagePath =[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",@"cached"]];
[imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:NO];
```