# How to Get PHAsset URL Synchronously

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44630089/6452805)  to get a `PHAsset` URL, but it run async.

I tried to synchronize it using `Semaphore`, `mutex` and `DispatchGroup`, but no one worked.

I decide to change that answer to get URL synchronously, but I couldn't do it.

Comment: Don't. Learn to understand asynchronous data processing.

Comment: You mean I should use callback? Couldn't do it without callback?

Comment: Yes, use a callback.

Comment: So this lead me to call all function before this function using closure. I mean there will be a sequence of callbacks. Is it OK to call all functions in this hierarchy with callback?

Comment: It depends on the design. For example if the asynchronous tasks are executed in a loop there is `DispatchGroup` to be notified when all tasks have finished.

Comment: Is it correct to call  `DispatchGroup` `enter` before call `getURL` (Async func that give a closure as completion) and call `leave` in callback?  I did it but it didn't work.